# Fedora doesn't boot since 4.5.7-202: grub shows only a blinking cursor

Tags: linux, boot, grub2, boot-loader

I have a Skylake system with **dualboot**: Linux and Windows.
I am using **grub2** as a bootloader.
**4.5.7-200 boots fine**, but 4.5.7-202 and the newly released 4.6.4-201 don’t boot up, grub shows a **blinking cursor** instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have this issue: https://www.happyassassin.net/2016/07/07/psa-failure-to-boot-after-kernel-update-on-skylake-systems/

It is related to a kernel update on Skylake cpu

In case the link dies here are some workarounds:

- Boot an older kernel.
- Boot with the kernel parameter dis_ucode_ldr.
- Downgrade the microcode_ctl package to version 2.1-11 or earlier and force an initramfs rebuild, either with dracut or by reinstalling the packages for the kernels that don’t boot.

Comment: Yep! That's it!